# C++ templated zip

Tags: c++, templates, zip

I have the following code of templated zip function:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2, typename R, R F( const T1, const T2)>
 inline std::vector< R> zip( const std::vector< T1> & v1, const std::vector< T2> & v2) {
     if( v1.size() != v2.size())
         throw exception( "Bad length!");

     typename std::vector< T2>::const_iterator it2 = v2.begin();
     std::vector< R> res;

     for( typename std::vector< T1>::const_iterator it1 = v1.begin();
                                                    it1!= v1.end();
                                                  ++it1)
     {
         res.push_back( F( *it1, *it2));
       ++it2;
     }

     return res;
 }
```

and I'm trying to use it like this:

```
class C {
public:
    static  C* foo( const C* c1, const C* c2) {
                return new C;
            }
};

std::vector< C*>  sum( const std::vector< C*> &v1, const std::vector< C*> &v2)
{
    return zip< C*, C*, C*, C::foo>( v1, v2);
}
```

getting:

```
error: could not convert template argument 'C::foo' to 'C* (*)(C*, C*)'
```

What should I do to make it compile and execute?

Comment: `C*` and `const C*` are different types.

Comment: Thank you, either this way, or the way which proposed M. M. in the answer this error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a type to the template list:

```
zip< C*, C*, C*, C::foo>( v1, v2);
                 ^^^^^^
```

Try this code

```
template< typename T1, typename T2, typename R, typename F>
inline std::vector<R> zip(const std::vector<T1> & v1,
                          const std::vector<T2> & v2, F f) {

     //...
     res.push_back( f( *it1, *it2));
     //...
}

//...

std::vector<C*>  sum(const std::vector< C*> &v1, const std::vector< C*> &v2)
{
    return zip< C*, C*, C*>( v1, v2, C::foo);
}
```

See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dd801608fda66d6) for a working code.

Comment: Everything is OK with such non-type template parameter. The problem is in `foo` function which is declared with `const C*` arguments. See [live example](http://ideone.com/FyZV6O).

Comment: I think I'll do like M M. proposed (put function as parameter). In my point of view, it's more proper in this case. But yes, it was the same old problem with const. So thanks both of you!

Comment: Note that, `R` can be deduced (in C++11: `decltype(std::result_of<F>::type)`), so you may call directly `zip(v1, v2, c::foo)`.

Comment: Thanks for advice, @Jarod42. Sadly, I can't use C++11 in my project, but this is really a good idea.